# Question title colour tough to read

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

The pale blue colour used for the question titles is pretty hard to read.  It looks great but needs to be darkened a little bit in my opinion.

Oh and one for the meta-meta: the colour used for the question titles used here on the meta site is worse.

Comment: I don't know, it looks fine to me. It's hex color `1F709C`, with saturation of almost 100% and brightness of 66%, which is not bad.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I am declining this request as the colors in the current build of our network sites seem to be sufficient, high-contrast, and easy to read.